# Varios Primary Key en SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Hola quiero una tabla en SQLite que tenga 2 campos como primary key y además un campo `id` que sea entero único. Por lo que he estado buscando es algo tal que así:

```
create table t (id integer, name string, phone string, nick string PRIMARY KEY(name, phone);
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero el campo `id` no se crea como entero `autoincrement`. Debería haberlo definido como:

```
create table t (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, .......)
```

Pero entonces no puedo poner los otros 2 campos como `primary key`. Por el campo `id` en principio no voy a buscar, sólo me interesa que sea un campo único. He probado diferentes variaciones y me dice que la tabla `t` tiene más de una `primary key`.

Gracias por la colaboración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partimos de los siguientes datos:

- Únicamente puede existir una clave primaria en una tabla.
- `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` es [un alias de `ROWID`](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

El primero impide que puedas definir tu campo `id` como autoincrementado y, posteriormente, lo uses como clave primaria junto a `name` y `phone`, pero olvidas que una ÍNDICE ÚNICO es funcionalmente lo mismo que una CLAVE PRIMARIA:

```sql
create table t (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name string,
  phone string,
  nick string,
  UNIQUE INDEX(id, name, phone)
);
```

Funcionalmente tienes resuelto tu problema con la clave única, pero también tienes que tener en cuenta que [sqlite mantiene un identificador de registro](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) de manera automática que puedes usar para sustituir tu `id` que se referencia mediante los campos `rowid`, `oid` or `_rowid_`.

Podrías omitir dicho campo de la declaración y usar como clave primaria `name` y `phone`:

```sql
create table t (
  name string,
  phone string,
  nick string,
  PRIMARY KEY(name, phone)
);
```

Implícitamente el `rowid` será único y por lo tanto, funcionalmente, formaría parte de la clave primaria.

Debes acordarte de que, en caso de usar `*` en tus consultas, debes obtener explícitamente ese campo usando, por ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT rowid, * FROM t ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo te recomendaría usar el ID como clave primaria y utilizar la restricción de unicidad en nombre y teléfono:

Ver https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#uniqueconst

```
create table t (
 id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
 name string, 
 phone string, 
 nick string );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i1 ON t(phone, name);
```